# Save graph in a project folder from program in python and pyplot graph in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, graph, plotly

I'm writing in python a program to recognize emotions from voice (it's a web interface and I'm using flask). I passed the variables in JavaScript I created a graph using Plotly. Only now I want to save the graph in a project specific folder called "graphs". How can I do?

I don't want to have to pass the graph from javascript to python and save it. if so how can I do it?

Here's how to build the graph in JavaScript

```js
const x1 = JSON.parse('{{data.audio_len}}');
const y1 = JSON.parse('{{data.val_outputs}}');
console.log(x1);
console.log(y1);

var data = [];
const trace1Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace1Values.push(y1[i][0]);
}
var Disgusto = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace1Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Disgusto",
};
data.push(Disgusto);

const trace2Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace2Values.push(y1[i][1]);
}
var Gioia = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace2Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Gioia",
};
data.push(Gioia);

const trace3Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace3Values.push(y1[i][2]);
}
var Paura = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace3Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Paura",
};
data.push(Paura);

const trace4Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace4Values.push(y1[i][3]);
}
var Rabbia = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace4Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Rabbia",
};
data.push(Rabbia);

const trace5Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace5Values.push(y1[i][4]);
}
var Sorpresa = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace5Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Sorpresa",
};
data.push(Sorpresa);

const trace6Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace6Values.push(y1[i][5]);
}
var Tristezza = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace6Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Tristezza",
};
data.push(Tristezza);

const trace7Values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  trace7Values.push(y1[i][6]);
}
var Neutrale = {
  x: x1,
  y: trace7Values,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  line: {
    shape: 'spline'
  },
  name: "Neutrale",
};
data.push(Neutrale);

var layout = {
  title: '{{data.name_audio}}',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Tempo audio in sec'
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Emozioni',
    range: [0, 1]
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<div class="grafico" id="myDiv" src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.0.min.js'></div>
```

I tried to use this code to save the graph in a folder of my project but when I run the code and show the graph it doesn't save me

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout).then(function () {
  Plotly.writeImage('myDiv', 
    { format: 'png', width: 300, height: 300 }, 
    { folder: 'grafico/grafico.png' });
});
```

Comment: `<div class="grafico" id="myDiv" src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.0.min.js'></div>` cannot be right. Don't you mean `<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.0.min.js'></script><div class="grafico" id="myDiv"></div>`

Comment: i tried but the graph is not saved

Comment: So there are more errors. Look in the console and see them

Comment: Non mi escono errori, solo che non mi salva il grafico

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]`, add example {data.audio_len} and {data.val_outputs} JSON or objects so we have a [mcve]